# Private Page View Counter

Tags: plugins

Is there a way to see the number of times a page has been viewed from the WP page/post lists on the dashboard? I don't want it to show publicly.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: WP doesn't track that information, you'll need to acquire the data from a service such as Google Analytics or Jetpack stats

Answer (score 1):

We've been using [WP-PostViews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postviews/) for years and it has never failed us. It adds a column with view count that is incremented with every load of the page - also works well with cached sites.